# Is it safe to close Minecraft's multiplayer server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am currently running a Minecraft server, and when I leave and rejoin to check if my stuff is still there, it is.

What happens when I close the server?  Does it matter if I just use the `x` button on the window?  Is anything lost or does it save before closing?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Everything will be saved and shut down when you close your Minecraft server with the `X` button -  nothing will be lost. If you want to feel extra safe, however, simply type `stop` into the command bar (or `/stop` into the chat window) to bring it to a graceful halt.

Comment: You could even use the `save-all` command before `stop` to force a full save of game data.

Comment: I have had issues with closing it without typing in stop.

Comment: @AttackingHobo could you elaborate?

Comment: is there any countdown command?

Answer (score 5):

This is a very old question but I will answer to avoid anyone making the same mistake I did: **DON'T** just close your Minecraft server with the x button, you might lose the the last changes you made to your world. Minecraft's server has an autosave feature that triggers once in a while, if you just kill the server process you might lose the last changes. **ALWAYS** use the `/stop` command before quitting the server.

Comment: Agree 100%. My world running on Bedrock server 1.19.1.01 for Windows got badly corrupted (two chunks missing around where I was building), due to me just killing the window running the server. I've subsequently found the "stop" command, and will be using that religiously going forward. Just closing the window via the [X] will work most of the time... until it doesn't!